# How to update Jetpack compose UI by override method or outside the function

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am converting my older XML UI as per requirement.
in there,
I am unable to update by Jetpack compose UI by my override function.
In some research I see many websites shows remember function helps for state update,
but,
as for my situation.
I need to update my UI by the override function that I implemented in another class.

```
    private lateinit var materialList: List<Material>


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (savedInstanceState == null)
            viewModel.initFilters(initText, initFilters)
        materialpresenter.attachView(this, lifecycle)

        materialList= listOf()
        setContent {
            FilterBox(materialList)
        }

    }


@Composable
fun FilterBox(materialList: List<Material>) {
    var selectedIndex by remember { mutableStateOf("0") }
    val onItemClick = { index: Int -> selectedIndex = "0" }

    FlowRow(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 14.dp),
        mainAxisAlignment = MainAxisAlignment.Start,
        crossAxisSpacing = 8.dp,
        mainAxisSpacing = 4.dp
    ) {
        materialList.forEach { hashTag ->
            if (selectedIndex == hashTag.id) {
                FilterSelectionItemText(
                    hashTag.slug, index = 0,
                    onClick = onItemClick
                )
            } else {
                FilterUnSelectionItemText(
                    hashTag.slug, index = 0,
                    onClick = onItemClick
                )
            }

        }
    }
}

    override fun onMaterials(list: List<Material>) {
        print("list :-" + list)
        materialList = list
    }
```

I want to update my **FilterBox** Composable UI by my **onMaterials** function.
because when I am print this this its printing data properly, but my UI is not updating.

Comment: remember is just save data between recompositions, it doesn't cause recompositions. All the magic is done by `mutableStateOf`, which can be used outside of composable, e.g. `private var materialList by mutableStateOf(listOf<Material>())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update composable UI you first need state which holds data
because composable functions are updating when there is a some state/data changes

in this example your data is `materialList: List<Material>`

You need to wrap your data with state / mutable state / mutable state list (for lists)

Change your list to stateList or mutableState...

```
private val materialList: MutableState<List<Material>> = mutableStateOf(emptyList())
```

Collect your data from state in `setContent` composable like:

```
val myList: List<Material> by materialList // here you will get updated last data as List<Material>

FilterBox(myList)
```

Update state from overridden method.

```
  override fun onMaterials(list: List<Material>){
        materialList.value = list // your updated List
    }
```